# App Engine Datastore: entity design and query optimization

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

*I have a system where users can vote on entities, if they like or hate them. It will be bazillion votes and trazillion records, hopefully, some time in the future :)*

At the moment i store a vote in an Entity like this:

```
UserRecordVote: recordId, userId, hateOrLike
```

And when i want to get every Record the user liked i do a query like this:

I query the "UserRecordVote" table for all the "likes", then i take the recordIds from that resultset, create a key of that property and get the record from the Record Table.

Then i aggregate all that in a list and return it.

#### Here's the question:

*I came up with a different approach and i want to find out if that one is 1. faster and 2. how much is the difference in cost.*

I would create an Entity which's name would be userId + "likes" and the key would be the record id:

```
new Entity(userId + "likes", recordId)
```

So when i would do a query to get all the likes i could simply query for all, no filters needed. AND i could just grab the entity key! which would be much cheaper if i remember the documentation of app engine right. (can't find the pricing page anymore). Then i could take the Iterable of keys and do a single get(Iterable keys). Ok so i guess this approach is faster and cheaper right? But what if i want to grab all the votes of a user or better said, i want to grab all the records a user didn't vote on yet.

#### Here's the real question:

I wan't to load all the records a user didn't vote on yet:
So i would have entities like this:

```
new Entity(userId+"likes", recordId);
```

and

```
new Entity(userId+"hates", recordId);
```

I would query both vote tables for all entity keys and query the record table for all entity keys. Then i would remove all the record entity keys matching one of the vote entity keys and with the result i would get(Iterable keys) the full entities and have all the record entites which are not in one of the two voting tables.

*Is that a useful approach? Is that the fastest and cost efficient way to do a datastore query? Am i totally wrong and i should store the information as list properties?*

EDIT:
With that approach i would have 2 entity groups for each user, which would result in million different entity groups, how would GAE Datastore handle that? Atleast the Datastore Viewer entity select box would probably crash :) ?

Comment: Having an entity kind per user is not going to work really well. A much better solution would be to base the key name on a combination of user ID and record ID.

Comment: so I would have an Entity("UserRecordVote", userId + "_" + recordId) with the recordId and userId as an aditional property so i can filter on that? then i would run the query, grab the keys only, split it and do the 2nd query...? would atleast save me some cash because the first query is for keys only.

Comment: does that still perform well?

Comment: Yes - and that's pretty much Brett Slatkin's relation index pattern from his Google I/O talk. If you'll always be looking up one or the other, you can make the entities children of that one, and base the key name only on the other, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the Real Question, you probably want to have your hateOrLike field store an integer that indicates either hated/liked/notvoted.  Then you can filter on hateOrLike=notVoted.

The other solutions you propose with the dynamically named entities make it impossible to query on other aspects of your entities, since you don't know their names.

The other thing is you expect this to be huge, you likely want to keep a running counter of your votes rather than tabulating every time you pull up a UserRecord - querying all the votes, and then calculating them on each view is very slow - especially since App Engine will only return 1000 results on each query, and if you have more than 1000 votes, you'll have to keep making repeated queries to get all the results.

If you think people will vote quickly, you should look into using a sharded counter for performance.  There's examples of that with code available if you do a google search.

Comment: what if i know i don't want to query on other aspects of that entity, would that approach be still cheaper and faster than the double query? one query to get the non voted record ids and one to get the real entities? with the dynamically named entities i would only pay for quering the keys in the first query

Comment: anyways i will probably need the sharding counters because i also keep track of a vote counter: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Comment: If you don't want to query on other aspects, I think you're kinda along the the right track, but instead of generating a new Entity kind, just generate a key name using the resource id + "hated"/"liked" (same as what Nick Johnson suggested).  However, when you fetch them, you will have to get them one by one, by key name.  This may be cheaper.  I don't know about performance, I'm guessing a fetch by index will be processed in parallel by the datastore, whereas your gets will occur sequentially, and might be slower in wall time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider serializing user hate/like votes in two separate TextProperties inside the entity. Use the userId as key_name.

```
rec = UserRecordVote.get_by_key_name(userId)
hates = len(rec.hates.split('_'))
etc.
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea if he's expecting more than a few hundred votes per record, or update rates greater than about 1 per second.